# Cannot delete Amazon S3 object

Tags: amazon-s3

I have the following Amazon S3 object:

[image]

I cannot delete it.  I have tried aws cli, 3Hub, and Amazon's Management Console.  When I try using aws cli or 3Hub, I get a key does not exist error.  When I try Amazon's Management Console, the object always reappears with the same last modified date.

I have noticed that the object has that %0A (linefeed?) on the end of the link and suspect that this is part of the problem.

How can I delete this object?

I have also opened a thread in the AWS forums here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=142946&tstart=0.  I have also created a private support ticket -- which is getting good Amazon attention.

**Update**

Other things I am trying:

- Using the [s3curl](http://aws.amazon.com/code/128) tool (didn't work)
- Using the [AWS S3 CLI rm](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/rm.html) tool (didn't work)
- Using the `fixbucket` command from [s3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) (didn't work)
- Using a lifecycle rule (this worked after about 24 hours):

[image]

Comment: have u set the `permission` of `upload/delete` for your credentials inside `Properties`

Comment: When I try to change the permission of the object in the console, I get an "object does not exist" error.

Comment: object is S3 Bucket `name` or `key`??

Comment: can you refresh your Bucket again??

Comment: Object details are above.  I have refreshed the bucket and the object is still there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3s lifecycle rules unfortunately do not accept wildcards. You will have to specify the fill in the ** in 'media/**/'. You do not need the * after 'Icon' however since lifecycle rules accept a prefix, which means that all keys prefixed with what you supply will be deleted.

Comment: Good point.  If I change it to ```Icon```, will it catch anything in any directory that starts with ```Icon```?

Comment: I changed the prefix to ```media/Icon``` and it has not worked.

Comment: It took about 24 hours for this change to take effect.  Now if there was a way to apply this to multiple subdirectories...